# Identifying transistors

Tags: transistors, identification, gain, darlington

I have found an old driver board (probably the mid 80's) for stepper motors (rated at 1.25V 3.8A) and I want to rebuild the H-Bridge using the parts on the board and a micro-controller as an input. I have the schematics but the ICs (mainly the transistors) are marked with proprietary numbers (not the typical TIP 120 for example). From the schematics and the board I know that I have PNP  darlington (called 3825) and NPN darlington (called 3805) transistors. Having no datasheet for the transistors I built a simple circuit to measure the gain:

[image: Test circuit]

Measuring the current between the emitter and the ground I get 0uA. Across the 1M resistor I get 8.89V and 0V across the 1K resistor. Measuring the voltage between the collector and emitter I get 9V.

I added a push button but pressing the button only changes the voltage between 8.99V and 9V (Although I'm not sure my multimeter is that precise).

[image]

So where did I miss something?

PS: My multimeter as an hFE function but cannot read gains higher than 999 and my guess is that those have higher gains than that.

Comment: Are you sure they aren't 2N3805 and 2N3825 transistors? Neither are common, though--I struggle to even find datasheets. Also, your battery is upside-down.

Comment: Because of the resistors that Spehro mentions, to test it you'll want to support about \$100\:\mu\text{A}\$ into the base. So perhaps something of \$\le 100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ to the base. That means you'll need to support on the order of \$100\:\text{mA}\$ at the collector, more or less. So about a tenth of what you show on the collector, too.

Comment: On just a lark, I did find a 2SC3805. The 2SC3805 is an NPN and it is a power device, too. But it is a high voltage device for horizontal flyback use, I think, and it's definitely not a Darlington. Probably not it. I also may have just found the 2SC3825. Looks like 500 V, 4 A, NPN. Panasonic and Matsushita (C3825).

Comment: What package are they in?

Comment: the internal resistors in Sphero's answer would mean that you need to use a lower base resistor for your tests  (try 10K)

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are not 2N3805 since they drive stepper motor that well above the max power of those. They are in a TO-220 package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most integrated [Darlington](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TIP120-D.PDF) pair power transistors have resistors so you would need a realistic current at the base and collector.

[image]

You could measure the resistance from base to emitter with an ohmmeter (the higher value of the two polarities, if one is higher, will be the correct one).

Comment: I still get 0uA using 2 different multimeter with 100k and 100ohms resistors. However now I get 0.25V across the 100 ohm resistor and 8.74V across the 100k resistor.

Comment: If you have 0.25V across the 100 ohm resistor you have 2.5mA. Could the current range fuses in your multimeters be blown?